# Swift: How can I remove duplicates from an array of doubles?

Tags: arrays, swift, duplicates

I have an array of values like `[0.75, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0040000000000000001, ...]` and I need to remove the duplicates. I only want to focus on the first 3 digits after the decimal point. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NumberFormatter to fix the minimum and maximum fraction digits and use a set to filter the duplicate elements:

```
let array = [0.75, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0040000000000000001]

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 3
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3
```

---

```
var set = Set<String>()
let orderedSet: [Double] = array.flatMap {
    guard let string = numberFormatter.string(for: $0) else { return nil }
    return set.insert(string).inserted ? $0 : nil
}

orderedSet   // [0.75, 0.005, 0.004]
```

If you need Strings (as suggested by @Hamish):

```
var set = Set<String>()
let orderedSet: [String] = array.flatMap {
    guard let string = numberFormatter.string(for: $0) else { return nil }
    return set.insert(string).inserted ? string : nil
}

orderedSet   // ["0.750", "0.005", "0.004"]
```

Comment: This returns `[0.75, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0040000000000000001]`

Comment: I can return strings if you want

Comment: Yea, that would work. Then I can convert them to doubles later.

Comment: In your first example, you could also say `return set.insert(string).inserted ? $0 : nil` instead of the if-else, and just replace `$0` with `string` to get array of strings (no need to do a separate `flatMap`).

Comment: @Hamish Much better. I do prefer also ternary operator.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem strongly suggests you're using the wrong type for your data. Rather than trying to fix it up at the point of uniquing, I suspect you really just want to modify your model so the issue doesn't occur.

If you want to do decimal-based math, you should use decimal-based numbers, like `NSDecimalNumber`. For example, considering the case where you do have doubles coming into the system, you can convert them to `NSDecimalNumber` with a "0.001 accuracy" this way:

```
let values = [0.75, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0040000000000000001]

let behavior = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .plain,
                                      scale: 3,
                                      raiseOnExactness: false,
                                      raiseOnOverflow: false,
                                      raiseOnUnderflow: false,
                                      raiseOnDivideByZero: false)

let decimalNumbers = values.map {
    NSDecimalNumber(value: $0).rounding(accordingToBehavior: behavior)
}

let uniqueDecimals = Set(decimalNumbers)
```

Once you are working with `NSDecimalNumber`, and applying the appropriate rounding rules, then most operations work as you expect. You can just put them into a `Set` to unique them. You can check for equality. You can print them, and they will behave like decimal numbers. Make your model match your meaning, and most other problems disappear.

Comment: Thank you. I got completely lost looking for that init.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but I just watched your [`Do iOS 2016`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_S6UOrwS-Tg) talk. I loved it, and it's going to be my go-to for explaining sum-types vs product-types, and why people shouldn't use parallel arrays to store data members that should be bound together in a struct. Great work! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a little bit complicated as your equality for Doubles is based *on the first 3 digits after the decimal point*. Many threads describe about removing duplicates where simple equality applies, but I cannot find one including Doubles with comparison in your question.

You usually use `Set` to eliminate duplicates, but `Set<Double>` uses strict equality which does not fulfill your requirement.

Normalizing the value may work in your case:

```
extension Double {
    var my_normalized: Double {
        return (self * 1000).rounded() / 1000
    }
}

print(0.0050000000000000001.my_normalized == 0.0051.my_normalized) //->true
```

Using this, you can write something like this:

```
let arr = [0.75, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0040000000000000001 /*,...*/]

var valueSet: Set<Double> = []
var result: [Double] = []
arr.forEach {value in
    let normalizedValue = value.my_normalized
    if !valueSet.contains(normalizedValue) {
        valueSet.update(with: normalizedValue)
        result.append(value)
    }
}
print(result) //->[0.75, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0040000000000000001]
```

If you do not mind the order of the result and it can contain normalized value, the code can be simpler:

```
let simpleResult = Array(Set(arr.map {$0.my_normalized}))
print(simpleResult) //->[0.75, 0.0050000000000000001, 0.0040000000000000001]
```